# Kafka partition rebalancing

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is partition rebalancing a common thing when we have multiple partitions in our kafka topics?

It doesn’t necessarily mean we have some latency or some issue in our app?

I have been seeing logs of the partitions being revoked and reassigned.

Comment: Do you mean leader election or consumer group rebalancing? "Partition rebalancing" isn't a thing

Comment: I meant consumer group rebalancing. Also,there is a thing called as "Partition rebalancing" https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html.

Comment: It's somewhat of an overloaded term, I guess. Sure, partition *assignments* are rebalanced to consumer instances. Data within partitions is not "rebalanced"

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes, rebalancing would mean you could have an unstable/idle client, the brokers are "unhealthy" for a variety of reasons, or other network/OS level issues... When a rebalance happens, there is no consumption happening, therefore introducing lag.

To get better insights into the Kafka cluster and the clients, it would be recommended to [look over JMX metrics](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html) in addition to other system-level metrics such as network, CPU, memory, disk, etc.  rather than only Kafka process logs

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Consumer Groups ? Normally the msg "partitions being revoked and reassigned"- is seen in below 2 scenarios.

Let's say you have a Consumer group of 3 Consumers and each consumes\processes 1 Kafka broker partitions individually.

Scenario 1-

Suppose consumer 3 goes down for some reason.

Subsequently kafka revokes the partition assignment to 3rd consumer temporarily (till it is up and running) and re-assigns the partition to either of consumer 1 or 2.

In such kind of scenario , we see such msg.

Scenario - 2

Additionally when consumer 3 is up later, it will be re-assigned partition to consume to process. 
And you will see the same msg again.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your question about rebalancing being common thing or not.

If an application seeing too much of relancing then certainly it says something is wrong with the application or may be something wrong at broker side. So it is not a common thing in this case.

While this is perfectly common when you see this event less often like at the start of application or in-between any failover between consumers.

**Considerable Point :**

- Rebalance time window is **no-avaiablity** for consumers as they won't be able to read any messages until rebalance finishes which may be hurting your overall through put if too much rebalance is happening.